# How to convert segy to npz?

Tags: python, sobel

I'm new to programming.

I need to convert my seismic section (segy) to compressed array (npz) in order for me to load inside `Jupyter` to run some algorithms.

How do I convert `segy` to `npz` format?
Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: Look at `obspy` to read `segy` file: https://docs.obspy.org/master/packages/obspy.io.segy.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the segy module, but to save to an npz file format, you can use the [scipy.parse](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) package to convert a regular nupmy array to a sparse/compressed array.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
import numpy as np
dense = np.array(*your np array here*)
sparse = sp.csr_martrix(dense)
sp.save_npz('name.npz', sparse, compressed=True)
```

This will convert the regular numpy array to be saved as the compressed matrix file in .npz. Therefore, the only problem left is to convert the segy to numpy, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I have yet discover where to start.